# PBDOM : Exporting to XML file gives a single line

Tags: xml, dom, line-breaks, powerbuilder

I've been starting developing with PowerBuilder 12.5 a few weeks ago. I had to write some XML files, so I got familiar with the PBDOM library.

I can build a lot of different things, it's very nice, but one thing still bothers me :
In the output file, **the whole XML is written on a single line**.

I use the **SaveDocument** function.

For example, here is some code :

```
PBDOM_Document              doc
PBDOM_Element               noderoot, node1, node11, node12

doc = CREATE PBDOM_Document
doc.NewDocument("NodeRoot")
noderoot = doc.GetRootElement()

node1 = CREATE PBDOM_Element
node1.SetName("Node1")
noderoot.AddContent(node1)
node1.SetAttribute("Attr", "AttrValue")

node11 = CREATE PBDOM_Element
node11.SetName("Node11")
node11.AddContent("Here is a value")
node1.AddContent(node11)

node12 = CREATE PBDOM_ELEMENT
node12.SetName("Node12")
node12.AddContent("Here is another value")
node1.AddContent(node12)

doc.SaveDocument("myDoc.xml")
```

Here is the result when I open it with notepad++

```
<NodeRoot><Node1 Attr="AttrValue"><Node11>Here is a value</Node11><Node12>Here is another value</Node12></Node1></NodeRoot>
```

Whereas I wanted :

```
<NodeRoot>
    <Node1 Attr="AttrValue">
        <Node11>Here is a value</Node11>
        <Node12>Here is another value</Node12>
    </Node1>
</NodeRoot>
```

With the notepad++ XML tools plugin, I can use the "pretty print" function to get this nice representation. But I would like my file to be formatted this way from the beginning.
I noticed that the "line ending" was set to UNIX format (indicator on bottom right of the window), but I'm working on Windows. When I use the menu to convert it to Windows format (CR+LF), it changes this indicator, but the code stays on one single line.

Is there a way to tell PBDOM to export the XML file with a nice output ?

Thank you !

Notes :
- Opening the XML file with Internet Explorer or Google Chrome gives me a nice vizualisation, with indentation, line breaks...
- Adding a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>` does not help (I've been doing it while exporting some more complex files, but I still get the output on one line...)

Comment: xml is a format defined to ease the information exchange between programs and not aimed to be read by humans. I doubt you can output pretty printed xml from pbdom.

Comment: I agree with you. It was for mere vizualisation.
On this link : http://scn.sap.com/message/14841489
Someone helped me and found a workaround : transmitting the string to an pair of OLEObject MXXML writer and reader, setting the right properties, then exporting the string back.  
It's sad that these objects had that property but PBDOM didn't...
But at least there's a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pbdom to write the xml document, you can do as below if possible:

1. Create a datawindow object with necessary fields.
2. Design the xml template inside datawindow design view.
3. Important: in the export property tab of datawindow there is one option called "Include White Space", check it.
4. At run time populate data in the datawindow/datastore.
5. Do a saveas of the datawindow/datastore with saveas type xml.

Now you will have a xml document that is well formatted. It's very easy also.

see if this helps.